# What's the difference between portal key levels?

Tags: ingress

What's the difference between a L1 vs. a L8 portal key? Do they do different things?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Portal keys don't have a level.

What probably confuses you is that a level is shown when you view the portal keys in your inventory, but that shows what level the corresponding *portal* has at the moment.

Comment: They do indeed show it as though it were the level of the portal key, and I guess in a sense a key to a L4 portal is a level 4 portal key, but indeed it is not meaningful.